# Why the reflexivity of a Banach set depend on the bijectivity of $Jx(f)=f(x)$?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E$ a Banach set. We say that $E$ is reflexive if $$J: E\to E^{''}$$
where $$Jx(f)=f(x)$$ is bijective (where $E''$ is the topological bidual). Now, I know if there is a bijective isometry $E\to F$, then $E$ and $F$ are the same (in a sense that is still not clear... but anyway). Now in Brezis functional analysis book (analyse fonctionnelle published by Dunod) page 43 remark 13, they say that : "We must use $J$ in the definition of reflexivity because there are spaces $E$ such that there is an onto isometry $E\to E''$ but $E$ is not reflexive".

I thought that if there is a bijective isometry between two spaces $A$ and $B$, then $A$ and $B$ are the same... So why do we must talk $J$ in the definition of reflexivity ? (since if there is a bijective isometry between two spaces they are the same).

Answer (score 1):

Reflexivity [in the $j:X\rightarrow X^{**}$ sense]is equivalent to weak compactness of the unit ball.  The requirement that this map be onto is quite specific.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you agree that it's equivalent to a reflexivity in $k:x\to X^{**}$ where $k(x)(f)=2f(x)$ for example ? i.e. we don't need an isometry, just a homeomorphism that preserve balls.

Comment: I mean $k:X\to X^{**}$ (not $k:x\to X^{**}$)